# how to convert RawQuerySet to int

Tags: django

i know this is a strange question but i need to reduce one from the RawQuerySet. i need to reduce a the value output by the .raw command but i do not know how to do this. i have tried to convenvert the RawQuerySet to the

- queryset
- dictionary
- tuple

but i don`t know what to do from their. i am getting the data in the following query

```
data = bio_eq.objects.raw('SELECT bio_eq_amount from bio_lab_bio_eq where bio_eq_id=bio_eq_id')
```

i am not sure how to take this and extract the data and turn it into a integer

Comment: If you need just an integer and not run raw SQL to get model instances, I'd use a cursor: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''SELECT bio_eq_amount from bio_lab_bio_eq where bio_eq_id=bio_eq_id''')

row = cursor.fetchone()

integer_value = int(row[0])
```